# The approximation property of group C*-algebras

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, amenability

Let $G$ be a discrete group. Then the group C*-algebra $C^*(G)$ is nuclear if and only if $G$ is amenable. I am wondering whether nuclearity of $C^*(G)$ can fail for a Banach-space reason, namely due to lack of the approximation property. (Let me recall that nuclearity is just the approximation property with respect to u.c.p. maps factoring through matrix algebras.) Hence my question.

> Is there any example of a group $G$ (to make life easier let me allow uncountable groups where pathologies are more likely to appear) such that $C^*(G)$ lacks the approximation property?

Comment: It doesn't answer your question, but it seems worth noting that there are non-amenable discrete groups whose reduced Cstar algebras have MAP. (Free groups are the first examples, due to Haagerup in the 1970s).

Comment: Also, I don't quite understand your 3rd sentence: lack of AP forces ${\rm C}^*(G)$ to be non-nuclear, while non-nuclearity does not imply lack of AP

Comment: Yes, this is what I am saying in my 3rd sentence, am I not?

Comment: OK, I get what you mean now. I think it was your mention of nuclearity that confused me slightly

Comment: The only source of C*-algebras without AP (or even MAP) is Szankowski's paper (1981). Probably it's reasonable to conjecture that the full group C*-algebra of a non-abelian free group lacks AP, but the problem seems hopeless. BTW if there is an uncountable example, then there is a countable example, because $C^*(G)$ is a union of $C^*(H)$, H countable subgroups, and $C^*(H)$ is complemented in C*(G).